# Is it possible to save a model file that is compatible with version control tools?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a large library of Simulink models that live in an SVN repository. The model files are text which caused us issues of bad/strange merges of changes. As a result we have changed all file nominations to binary and are handling the merges manually. This is a big process.

A bigger complication is that whenever a model file is touched, its internal content is changes with compute model versions, high water mark numbers, last changed times etc. This creates a lot of noise on the checkin of the model that doesn't represent any real change to the model functionality. Is there a way of saving models without any of this swarf?